# Optimizing linked DLLs

Tags: c++, optimization, shared-libraries

When "whole program optimization" is specified as a compiler switch, optimization is performed across .obj boundaries. This got me thinking: If I link my own executable to a DLL that I myself have built, am I losing optimization that the compiler could possibly have done if it had access to its .obj files?

Comment: Yes you are.  Whether that's important in any particular context is a different question.

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm just wondering from a conceptual point of view. One can argue that if the DLL itself is optimized enough then it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Well, there's still the overhead of the function call, which, in the case of a DLL, usually involves an extra level of indirection.  For a toy function which the compiler (or linker) might otherwise be able to inline, this can be punitive.

Comment: @PaulSanders does this overhead remain even after the DLL is loaded into memory? Am I able to help the compiler in this regard by providing the DLL source information?

Comment: Yes it does.  The obvious thing to do is to define any time-critical functions as inline functions in the DLL's header file.

Comment: The flip side of course is that you can't update inlined function by shipping just a new DLL. Even though they may be defined in the DLL's source code, they live in the EXE. Does this matter to you? We can't know.

Comment: A DLL is built once for all, like an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct - whole-program/link-time optimization can not optimize past shared library boundaries. On a positive side strict function-level boundary between executable and a library allows easier library updates when e.g. bugs are fixed or new features are released.